# Migration of MySQL database data to SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to export data from MySQL database to SQL server database.Is there any way which can be done without using 3rd party tool like SSMA,etc by using power shell scripts or bash scripts
In the below link they have explained with Ubuntu but I need using windows can help it out
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu

I don't want to use 3rd part tools so is there anyway by powershell or bash scri[pts that should be run in windows only.

Answer (score 0):

If you have backed up data from MySQL database you can use [SQL Server Management Studio](https://help.fasthosts.co.uk/app/answers/detail/a_id/513/~/importing-a-mssql-database-with-sql-server-management-studio-express-2014) it self.

Comment: It is a 3rd party tool. Is there anyway from powershell scripts and bash scripts